# One react player start another react player automatically to stop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

[react player npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)
We are using multiple react player in one Component, when starting one more player all are playing at the same time. I need One react player start automatically to stop another react player.Here attached a sample image
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Hi Smack! Did you solve this problem? If you've solved this problem, could you share your answer, please? I have a same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily set  key of the video that user clicked and started playing and set
playing true only if id/key matches.

```
     // set key of the video user started playing 
     const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(false); 

     //Looping video player
    {episodes && episodes.map((episode, key) => {
       <ReactPlayer
        id="VideoPlayer"
        url={someurl}
        className='react-player'
        playing={activeIndex === ky  ? true : false}
       >
      )}
```